# I am having some basic compile issues defining a BorderBrush

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am having some basic compile issues defining a BorderBrush.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderbrush.aspx
states that you define a borderbrush like this:

```
myBorder1 = new Border();
myBorder1.BorderBrush = Brushes.SlateBlue;
```

but in my code, when I try

```
border1.BorderBrush = Brushes.SlateBlue;
```

I get
`Error  1   The name 'Brushes' does not exist in the current context`
and I have included the namespace
`System.Windows.Controls`
as a "using" statement at the top of the file
as well as a Reference to the project.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
myBorder1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SlateBlue);
```

`Silverlight` doesn't have a `Brushes` class

Comment: Also might be worth nothing that SolidColorBrush is in System.Windows.Media.

Answer (score 0):

Brushes is inside System.Drawing... I have it by default, maybe you took it out???